# Install SWIGged Python library into dist-packages/myfoo.py, not dist-packages/myfoo/myfoo.py

Tags: python, c++, swig, distutils

I have a directory structure like

```
 setup.py
 myfoo/
     myfoo.i
     myfoo.cpp
     myfoo.hpp
```

with `setup.py`,

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
    name='myfoo',
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            '_myfoo',
            [
                'myfoo/myfoo.cpp',
                'myfoo/myfoo.i'
            ],
            swig_opts=['-c++'],
            )
        ],
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['myfoo'],
    requires=[]
    )
```

`myfoo.hpp`

```
#ifndef MYFOO_HPP
#define MYFOO_HPP

int myfoo();

#endif  // MYFOO_HPP
```

`myfoo.cpp`

```
#include "myfoo.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int myfoo() {
  std::cout << "hey!" << std::endl;
  return 42;
}
```

When running `python setup.py install`, the package builds correctly and installs the files

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
    _myfoo.so
    myfoo/
        myfoo.py
        myfoo.pyc
```

By default, only `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` is in the `$PYTHONPATH`, so `import myfoo` from anywhere yields an import error. For that to work, either both `myfoo.py[c]` should be in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` or be renamed to `__init__.py`. It seems that I didn't call `setup.py` correctly.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing

```
packages=['myfoo'],
```

and adding

```
py_modules = ['myfoo'],
package_dir = {'' : 'myfoo'}
```

to `setup.py` does the trick.

Comment: Instead of the `package_dir`, it is enough to do `py_modules` and adding `build_ext --inplace` when calling `setup.py`